# Is log(n!) = Θ(n·log(n))?

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion, complexity-theory, big-o

I am to show that **log(*n*!) = Θ(*n*·log(*n*))**.

A hint was given that I should show the upper bound with ***n*<sup>*n*</sup>** and show the lower bound with **(*n*/2)<sup>(*n*/2)</sup>**.  This does not seem all that intuitive to me.  Why would that be the case?  I can definitely see how to convert ***n*<sup>*n*</sup>** to ***n*·log(*n*)** (i.e. log both sides of an equation), but that's kind of working backwards.

What would be the correct approach to tackle this problem?  Should I draw the recursion tree?  There is nothing recursive about this, so that doesn't seem like a likely approach..

Comment: You should really write it including the "as n -> ∞ "

Comment: Fun exercise: use the similar trick to show that the harmonic series 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ... diverges to infinity.

Comment: Shouldn't this be at cs.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @CodyBugstein, cs.stackexchange.com didn't exist back when the question was asked

Answer (score 399, accepted):

Remember that

```
log(n!) = log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(n-1) + log(n)
```

You can get the upper bound by

```
log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(n) <= log(n) + log(n) + ... + log(n)
                                = n*log(n)
```

And you can get the lower bound by doing a similar thing after throwing away the first half of the sum:

```
log(1) + ... + log(n/2) + ... + log(n) >= log(n/2) + ... + log(n) 
                                       = log(n/2) + log(n/2+1) + ... + log(n-1) + log(n)
                                       >= log(n/2) + ... + log(n/2)
                                        = n/2 * log(n/2)
```

Comment: Interesting... Pushing this into a sum, there is an approximation that results in the theta notation itself (source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation)  a matter of how that is derived is entirely separate.  Nice lead, thanks!

Comment: This is a very nice proof for the upper bound: log(n!) = log(1) + ... + log(n) <= n log(n) => log(n!) = O(n log n). However, for proving the lower bound (and consequently big-tetha), you'll probably need Stirling's Approximation.

Comment: You don't need Sterling's approximation for a lower bound.  log(n!) = log(1) + ... + log(n) >= log(n/2) + ... + log(n) >= n/2 * log(n/2) = Omega(n log n).

Comment: @Keith: I don't get it yet. Could you (or someone) expand a few more terms for me in the "..." part of "log(n/2) + ... + log(n)" please? Thanks!

Comment: @j_random_hacker: `log(n/2) + log(n/2 + 1) + ... + log(n - 1) + log(n)` (larger half of the terms of `log(n!)`). Actually, I just read the question and saw that the clue is stated in the question. Basically, `(n/2)^(n/2) <= n! <= n^n` => `log((n/2)^(n/2))<=log(n!)<=log(n^n)` => `Θ(n/2 * log(n/2))<=log(n!)<=Θ(n*log(n))`

Comment: this explanation is similar to accepted answer, but has a bit more details: http://www.mcs.sdsmt.edu/ecorwin/cs372/handouts/theta_n_factorial.htm

Comment: For the lower bound, you can even get the constant correct by choosing the `1-1/\log n` largest terms instead of only the `1/2`, then you get `\log(n!) >= n(1-1/logn) * log(n/logn) ~ nlogn - nloglog n`.

Answer (score 53):

I realize this is a very old question with an accepted answer, but none of these answers actually use the approach suggested by the hint.

It is a pretty simple argument:

`n!` (= 1*2*3*...*n) is a product of `n` numbers each less than or equal to `n`.  Therefore it is less than the product of `n` numbers all equal to `n`; i.e., `n^n`.

Half of the numbers -- i.e. `n/2` of them -- in the `n!` product are greater than or equal to `n/2`.  Therefore their product is greater than the product of `n/2` numbers all equal to `n/2`; i.e. `(n/2)^(n/2)`.

Take logs throughout to establish the result.

Comment: This is actually just the same as the log version in the accepted answer but taking the logarithm after instead of before. (it more clearly uses the hint though)

Comment: How’s this different to the accepted answer?

Comment: @Harsh Check the edit history on the accepted answer and compare the timestamps to this answer.

Answer (score 35):

[image]

Sorry, I don't know how to use LaTeX syntax on stackoverflow..

Comment: This is a great explanation! 
I could follow this until step 7, but then I cannot decode the mathemagic that happens between step 7 and step 8... :-(

Comment: @Z3d4s The argument in step 7 is basically, that the first term on the right hand side is the dominant term and that log(n!) can therefore approximated by n*log(n) or that it is of order n*log(n) which is expressed by the big O notation O(n*log(n)).

Comment: @Z3d4s the what steps 7-8 conversion is saying that n*logn == log(n^n)  and for showing the bound here you can say the first term is always greater than the second term you can check for any larger values, and for expressing big-O complexity we will always take the dominating item of all. So n*logn contributes to the big-O time.

Comment: I am a beginner. Does step 7 means that log(n!) = nlog(n) + {some positive but non-dominating term} => log(n!) = O(nlog(n)) ? But I think should it not be Omega(nlog(n)) instead of O(nlog(n)) ? clear my doubts please.

Comment: @rsonx It's both - see the accepted answer, for example. Regarding the {some positive but non-dominating term} - actually all the elements of multiplication are < 1, therefore the product is < 1 as well. `log` brings it to negative values so the asymptotic result here is actually `O(nlogn) - {something}`. It remains to be proved if that something is insignificant asymptotically compared to `nlogn` - and this answer doesn't provide it. It doesn't affect the big-O but can affect the Omega. Anyway, this is overcomplication, see other answers

Comment: @Z3d4s Basically for n -> ∞ , (1/n) -> 0. Hence (1 - (k/n)) -> 1. thus log of the product term would tend towards 0

Comment: @Gilfoyle, the response to `Sorry, I don't know how to use LaTeX syntax on stackoverflow..` is that you can't use it.

Answer (score 17):

See [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):

> ln(n!) = n*ln(n) - n + O(ln(n))

where the last 2 terms are less significant than the first one.

Answer (score 12):

For lower bound,

```
lg(n!) = lg(n)+lg(n-1)+...+lg(n/2)+...+lg2+lg1
       >= lg(n/2)+lg(n/2)+...+lg(n/2)+ ((n-1)/2) lg 2 (leave last term lg1(=0); replace first n/2 terms as lg(n/2); replace last (n-1)/2 terms as lg2 which will make cancellation easier later)
       = n/2 lg(n/2) + (n/2) lg 2 - 1/2 lg 2
       = n/2 lg n - (n/2)(lg 2) + n/2 - 1/2
       = n/2 lg n - 1/2
```

lg(n!) >= (1/2) (n lg n - 1)

Combining both bounds :

1/2 (n lg n - 1) <= lg(n!) <= n lg n

By choosing lower bound constant greater than (1/2) we can compensate for -1 inside the bracket.

Thus lg(n!) = Theta(n lg n)

Comment: This extended derivation is needed because, "something" >= n/2 * lg(n/2) is not equal to omega(n lg n) which was mentioned in one of the previous comment.

Comment: This should read "a constant SMALLER than (1/2)" as we are trying to find a lower bound.  Any constant, c, smaller than (1/2) will eventually make c*n*logn <= (1/2)n*logn-(1/2)n, for a large enough n.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, I found your answers convincing but in my case, I must use the **Θ** properties:

```
log(n!) = Θ(n·log n) =>  log(n!) = O(n log n) and log(n!) = Ω(n log n)
```

to verify the problem I found this web, where you have all the process explained: http://www.mcs.sdsmt.edu/ecorwin/cs372/handouts/theta_n_factorial.htm

Answer (score 3):

Helping you further, where Mick Sharpe left you:

It's deriveration is quite simple:
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm -> Group Theory

> log(n!) = log(n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * 2 * 1) = log(n) + log(n-1) + ... + log(2) + log(1)

Think of n as *infinitly big*. What is infinite minus one? or minus two? etc.

> log(inf) + log(inf) + log(inf) + ... = inf * log(inf)

And then think of *inf* as n.

Comment: I disagree with this, because by this logic the argument could be made that n = O(n!) as such.  As per your claim, log(n!) = inf * log(inf). "Think of n as infinitely big". What is log(infinity)? Infinity. Therefore, inf * log(inf) is infinity. from the other side, n is the square root of n, times itself. as n gets infinitely large, the square root does too, so you get infinity * infinity, which also equals infinity. Infinity = Infinity: Q.E.D.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation
Stirling approximation might help you. It is really helpful in dealing with problems on factorials related to huge numbers of the order of 10^10 and above.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
eln(x) = x
```

and

```
(lm)n = lm*n
```

Comment: Actually, that's wrong:

1^(m^n) != 1^(m*n)

it must be

(1^m)^n = 1^(m*n)

Comment: Errr I mean L instead of 1 in the above comment.

Comment: He didn't write 1^(m^n) he wrote (l^m)^n

Comment: @CodyBugstein: There was an edit made to fix the problem, you commented years later when the error was hidden in the history

Answer (score 1):

If you reframe the problem, you can solve this with calculus! This method was originally shown to me via Arthur Breitman https://twitter.com/ArthurB/status/1436023017725964290.

First, you take the integral of log(x) from 1 to n it is `n*log(n) -n +1`. This proves a tight upper bound since log is monotonic and for every point n, the integral from `n` to `n+1` of `log(n)` > `log(n) * 1`. You can similarly craft the lower bound using `log(x-1)`, as for every point n, `1*log(n)` > the integral from `x=n-1` to `n` of `log(x)`. The integral of `log(x)` from `0` to `n-1` is `(n-1)*(log(n-1) -1)`, or `n log(n-1) -n -log(n-1)+1`.

These are very tight bounds!