# Possible explanation for why lg(n!)=O(nlg(n))

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is log(n!) = Θ(n·log(n))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-nlogn)

My "proof" for why lg(n!) is O(nlg(n)) is because n is polynomially larger than lg(n!), so therefore nlg(n) would always be polynomially larger than lg(n!). Is that an acceptable reason? or do you have to mathematically prove it (in which case I would not know how to deal with the factorial)

Answer (score 6):

The usual proof I've seen is that for sufficiently large *n*, *n! < n<sup>n</sup>*. Take the logarithm of both sides to get *log(n!) < log(n<sup>n</sup>)*. Since *log(b<sup>a</sup>) = a log(b)*, we get *log(n!) < n log(n)*.

Comment: `n^n` is *greater* than `n!` :)

Comment: @ChrisNash: Yes, I accidentally had my inequalities backwards. Already fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably do need something a bit more mathematically strict, but it's not too difficult. Since

```
 lg(n!) = lg 1 + lg 2 + lg 3 + ..... + lg n
```

you might consider the area under the graph of `y = lg x` and approximate it with the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_method . You'll get something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation .

Because it's 'little o' your rectangles need to bound above and below.

Answer (score 1):

Use stirling's approximation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

```
ln n! = n\ln n - n +O(ln(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Recall that ln(a⋅b) = ln(a) + ln(b).  Therefore, ln(n!) = ln(n⋅(n−1)⋅…⋅2⋅1) = ln(n) + ln(n−1) + … ln(2) + ln(1); this yields n⋅ln(n) ≤ ln(n!) by inspection.