# What is the answer for: n! = Θ( )?

Tags: math, big-o, complexity-theory

How do I find the answer for: n! = Θ( )?
Even Big O is enough. All clues I found are complex math ideas.

What would be the correct approach to tackle this problem? recursion tree seems too much of a work

the goal is to compare between n! and n^logn

Comment: Huh? `n! = Θ(n!)`. Are you looking for some other way to say "n!"?

Comment: Is `O(n!)` a bad answer? Also you cannot really say that a function is equal to `O` because `O` denotes a class of functions and such equality is nonsensical. It makes more sense to say belongs to.

Comment: @luk32 "=" is very commonly used here. As per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) - "Note that "=" is not meant to express "is equal to" in its normal mathematical sense, but rather a more colloquial "is"".

Comment: how is n! comparing to n^logn

Comment: @Dukeling OK. I just checked that, I give that it is controversial =). Even the mentioned wikipedia says people call it abuse of notation. They actually gave the same reasoning as I did. BTW I also don't like the `f = O()` notation because it gives the notion that you can compute it. While with `O` notations you can only compare things.

Answer (score 3):

`Θ(n!)` is a perfectly fine, valid complexity, so `n! = Θ(n!)`.

As Niklas pointed out, this is actually true for every function, although, for something like
`6x² + 15x + 2`, you *could* write `Θ(6x² + 15x + 2)`, but it would generally be preferred to simply write `Θ(x²)` instead.

---

If you want to compare two functions, simply plotting it on [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%21+and+n%5Elogn+for+n+from+0+to+6) might be considered sufficient to see that `Θ(n!)` functions grow faster.

[image]

To mathematically determine the result, we can take the `log` of both, giving us `log (n!)` and `log nlog n = log n . log n = (log n)2`.

Then, since [`log(n!) = Θ(n log n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-nlogn?rq=1), and `n log n > (log n)2` for any large `n`, we could derive that `Θ(n!)` grows faster.

The derivation is perhaps non-trivial, and I'm slightly unsure whether it's actually possible, but we're a bit beyond the scope of Stack Overflow already (try [the Mathematics site](https://math.stackexchange.com/) if you want more details).

Comment: In fact that holds for every function: `f(n) = Θ(f(n))` regardless of what *f* is.

Comment: This feels like a non-answer.

Comment: @G.Bach I actually somewhat agree, but, while the question is asking what it's asking, this is the answer (although I can't say I'd be particularly irritated if this question were to end up deleted). If the question were to be *changed* to ask how to compare the two given functions, that should be closed as off topic, since it belongs on [math.se].

Answer (score 0):

If you want some sort of "closed form" expressions, you can get n! = Ω((sqrt(n/2))^n) and n! = O(n^n). Note sure those are more useful.

To derive them, see that (n/2)^(n/2) < n! < n^n.

To compare against n^(log n), use limit rules; you may also want to use n = e^(log n).