# Is O((log n)!) polynomial?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I wanna find `O((log n)!)`. I think `O((log n)!)` and `O(n!)` are equal! Because I think when n is infinite `(log n)!` and `n!` are equal. Is it true? If yes how can I show that? If not is the `O((log n)!)` polynomial?

Comment: "when n is infinite (log n)! and n! are equal" - first, you could say that about *any* increasing functions. n, n^2, n^3, nlog(n), anything. Second, we cannot actually plug infinity into n! or (log n)!, and that is not what big-O notation describes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your follow up question is whether `(logn)!` is polynomially bounded. It is obviously not a polynomial itself. **Stirling’s Approximation** gives us

`n!≤en^[n+1/2]*e^(−n)`

So,

`(log n)!≤e(log n)^[1/2+log n]*e^(−log n)`

Now `(log n)^log n=(e^loglogn)^logn=e^[(logn)⋅(loglogn)]`

So, the order of growth is approximately `e^[(logn)(loglogn)−logn] =n^[(loglogn)−1]`

This is unfortunately not bounded by any polynomial, since `loglogn` will eventually exceed any positive integer.

For example, compare `(log n)!` with `n^2`.

At `n=e^10,(log n)!=3480`, while `(e^10)2≈4.85×108`

At `n=e^100,(log n)!≈10157`
, while `e^200≈1086`

Answer (score 2):

Since the proper math has already been done, let me add a more intuitive explanation of why `O(log(n)!) > O(n^c)` for any given `c`. We will assume the logarithm is base 2, and for simplicity choose `c` as 10. (The argument would work just as well with different numbers of general values).

So, why will `log(n)!` grow ever larger than `n^10`? Let's take a look at both functions' values at the powers of 2, more specificaly, how much greater they grew compared to the last power of 2. (`n = 2^p` from now on)

`log(2^p)! = p * log(2^(p-1))!`, `(2^p)^10 = 2^10 * (2^(p-1))^10`. This may seem complicated, but it tells us that the `log(n)!` function will multiply it's value at each `p`th power of `2` by `p`, but `n^10` will multiply it's value only by `1024`, so the `log(n)!` will grow ever larger eventually.

Also, `log(n)!` grows slower than any exponential, similar argument can be made by observing how much both function multiply their value when `n` grows by 1.

Answer (score 0):

lets get back to some basic mathematics:
we know that if log a > log b, then a>b :(log base is greater than 1)
[click here to get more on this](http://www.emathhelp.net/notes/algebra-2/trigonometry/logarithmic-inequalities/)

Now we know that **log(N!)=NLogN** ([see here for proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-%CE%98n-logn))

and holding same argument,we get, **log((log N)!)=logN logLogN** 
Since,
log(N!) is of polynomial degree ,and log((log N)!) is of logarithmic order,
clearly,
**O(N!) >O((logN)!)** 
hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

By using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) stating that $ n! ~ \sqrt{2 \pi n} \frac{n}{e}^n (1 + O(frac{1}{n})) $, and using the same formula for $ \log{n} $, one can check that for $ n! $ the leading factor is $ n ^ n $ while for $ \log{n}! $ the same factor becomes $ \log{n} ^ \log{n} $. By using the fact that $ \ln{n} \leq n - 1 $, I believe you can easily show that $ O(\log{n}!) $ is less than $ O(n!) $.