# Is log(n!) = O((log(n))^2)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I am practicing problems on asymptotic analysis and I am stuck with this problem.

Is `log(n!) = O((log(n))^2)` ?

I am able to show that

```
log(n!) = O(n*log(n)) 
(log 1 + log 2 + .. + log n <= log n + log n + ... + log n)
```

and

```
 (log(n))^2 = O(n*log(n)) 
(log n <= n => (log n)^2 <= n*logn )
```

I am not able to proceed further. Any hint or intuition on how to proceed further? Thanks

Comment: What do you want to show? Fact is that log(n!) is not in O((log n)^2).

Comment: This question is about mathematics and not about a programming algorithm.

Comment: @Henry Then how do I show that? Other than plotting a graph is there any more formal way to show that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accoriding to [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):

`log(n!) = n*log(n) - n + O(log(n))`

So clearly upper bound for `log(n!)` will be `O(nlogn)`

Lower bound can be calculated by removing first half of the equation as:

`log(1) + ... + log(n/2) + ... + log(n) = log(n/2) + ... + log(n)`
                                        
`= log(n/2) + ... + log(n/2)`
                                        
`= n/2 * log(n/2)`

So Lower bound is also `nlogn`. Clearly answer would be **NO**

Comment: But that was not the question!

Comment: `Is log(n!) = O((log(n))^2) ?` answer is NO @JanakyMurthy

Comment: @JanakyMurthy what kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: Actually when I viewed it for the first time, I could see only half of the  answer. I don't know why. Yes I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand this step `log(1) + ... + log(n/2) + ... + log(n) = log(n/2) + ... + log(n)`

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer to my own question. We will prove the following facts:

1) `n*log(n)` is a tight bound for `log(n!)`

2) `n*log(n)` is a upper bound for `(log(n))^2`

3)`n*log(n)` is not a lower bound for `(log(n))^2`

For proof of (1) see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-%CE%98n-logn).

Proof(2) & (3) is provided in the question itself.
growth rate of `log n` `<` growth rate of `n`. 
So growth rate of `log(n)^2` `<` growth rate of `n*log(n)`.
So  `log(n)^2 = o(n*log(n))` (Here I have used little-o to denote that growth rate of `n*log(n)` is strictly greater than growth rate of `log(n)^2`

So the conclusion is that `log(n!) = big-omega(log(n^2))`
Correct me if I have made any mistake

Comment: About proof 3, in the link given by you approach is same as mine for lower bound and his lower bound was `n/2*log(n/2)` @janaky