# Is n ≠ Θ(logn)?

Tags: algorithm, math, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

Question is asked with an intent to get/let understand how to verify **Asymptotic Θ notation**. A Homework question. I am to show that **n ≠ Θ(logn)**

Solution: Yes, n ≠ Θ(logn).

```
c1logn ≤ n ≤ c2logn => c2≥n/logn, Ɐ n≥n0 - Impossible
```

Why `c2≥n/logn` is not possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about [cs.se] or [math.se].

Comment: @Dukeling when u say Off-topic, what do you mean by that?

Comment: By ["off-topic"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) I mean the question is inappropriate for [so] and would be better suited to a different site. But [don't post it on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), and probably don't (delete and) reask or migrate it if you already got a satisfactory answer, unless you feel the question might have a lot of future value for others. Some time complexity questions are on topic, but this one's a bit too maths-heavy and code-light for here.

Comment: Guys, it's a complexity based question. I am aware that it is tending towards Maths and less towards code. But it will help beginners to understand.  I have started learning things, so please don't demoralise and remove hold. More over if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-%CE%98n-logn can exist, my question is worth being here.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it, c2 is a constant if your n gets large to what value will n/log(n) converge?

Comment: Thanks, understood it.

Answer (score 2):

Well,

```
 f(n) = Θ(g(n))
```

if and only if there's a finite limit value

```
 lim f(n)/g(n) = c > 0
   n -> +inf
```

which means that for any constants `c1 < c < c2` we can find `n0` such that `f(n)/g(n)` will be in the `[c1..c2]` range for all `n > n0` (put it differently `c1*g(n) < f(n) < c2*g(n)` when `n > n0`). 
In your case

```
 f(n) = n
 g(n) = log(n)
```

The limit is (let's use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule))

```
lim n/log(n) = lim 1/(1/n) = lim n = +inf
  n -> +inf      n -> +inf     n -> +inf
```

there's no such a *finite* constant `c` (and we can't select any `c2` constant such that `c < c2`).

Comment: Great explanation!! Never thought this way.

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

`c2 will always be less than n` for any value of n which causes a contradiction here. And so `c2 ≥ n/logn` is never possible.