# details of algorithm complexity, how to deal with log cases?

Tags: algorithm

I have seen the following  pseudocode:

```
for j=1 to n
    m=n
    while m>0
          //some instructions
          m=m/2
```

I can see that the outer loop is running n times, but when it gets into the while portion it makes a series of m/2. For example, if n=10 I would get roughly that m will take the values of 10,5,2,1 so approximately it will iterate 4 times; when n=100 the values of m would be 100,50,25,12,7,3,1 so approximately 7 iterations. For what I see that would be log n (with base=2) so the final answer would be: n*log n. Am I right?

The problem that I have is how to get the details of the while loop, I can do something like:

```
n/2=1
n=2 apply log b=2 to both sides, so I will get:
log (base 2) n=log (base 2) 2
log n=1
```

I have problems with this last part, what would be the correct mathematical deduction of this section?

Thanks

Comment: You can prove that it takes `log(n)` steps by induction

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the equation as repeated divisions by two.

So we want to find `x` when `n / 2^x = 1` where `x` is the number of divisions we need to preform (here I will use 1 because in real number arithmetic division by two will never produce zero and a 1 approximation is good enough for an upper bound)

Rearranging we get `n = 2^x` so now taking the log we have we have `log(n) = x`. So the `x` we need to reach 1, and therefore the time complexity for the inner loop is `log(n)`

Answer (score 1):

Let `K` represent the number of inner loops. So, `2^K` approximately equal to `n`. Thus, the number of inner loops is `K = log(2^K) = log(n)`.

To run the entire algorithm, `Sum[log(n)]` loops are required. This is equivalent to `log[Pi(n)] = log(n!)`.

Asymptotically, this is `O(n log(n))` as shown in [this SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-%CE%98n-logn).

Comment: It is `O(n^2 log(n))` but the tightest upper bound I am pretty sure is `O(n log(n))`

Comment: @Mitchel0022 Oh you are right, I was summing one-too-many times.