# How to find the tighest bounds for a function in terms of asymptotic growth?

Tags: function, complexity-theory

I am confused as to how I would go about finding the tightest bounds for a function in terms of asymptotic growth. Consider log(n!) as the function. How does one go about finding the tightest bounds? Obviously you can find functions that grow faster or slower and bound by that but I am really confused as to how to approach this type of problem. I do not want an answer just some guidance in the right direction.

Comment: I thnk a good start is by remembering `log(a*b*c...*z) = log(a)+log(b) +...log(z)`.

Comment: For `log(n!)` in particular, you can find some very clear answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395). This is also a good example on how to approach many such problems in general, so you might find it useful.