# Derive a while loop runs in $\Theta( \sqrt{n} )$

Tags: python, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I know for a fact that algorithm **A** runs in $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$, but how does one derive that fact?

Algorithm **A**

```
i = 0
s = 0
while s <= n:
    s += i
    i += 1
```

Here is what I am thinking. We know that **A** is upper-bounded by O(n), as we increment $s$ by more than 1 in each iteration. We also know that it must be lower-bounded by $\log n$, as we increment $s$ with by something less than $2^i$ in each iteration. (Correct me if I am wrong, these are just my thoughts ...).

Now, what else can we say about **A**? How do we derive that its time complexity is $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$?

Comment: Is that LaTeX syntax you're using  for math?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes

Comment: Note that questions about theoretical computer science have their own Stack Exchange site, at [cs.se]; SO is narrowly focused on *writing code*, and tools exclusively for that use.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I find it a little perplexing how other questions regarding time complexity is warmly welcomed on SO, when mine is not. (eg. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2095395/7123519 (a lot more theoretical than my question))

Comment: Our rules change over time -- and of course, some historical questions were added before [cs.se] existed at all. If you want an idea of current consensus, ask a question over on [meta], and feel free to link me to it; should there be a strong, current consensus there that questions about time complexity analysis are on-topic on SO proper, I'll honor it (as will others, when same is brought to attention).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time we increment `i`, we add `s` to `i`. This thus means that after `k` steps, `s` has grown to:

```
     k
    ---
    \
s = /   i
    ---
    i=0
```

This sequence is known. After the *k*-th step, there are *T<sub>k</sub>* numbers, with *T<sub>k</sub>* a [*triangular number* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). A shorter formula for *T<sub>k</sub>* is *T<sub>k</sub>=i×(i+1)/2*. *T<sub>k</sub>* thus scales *quadratic* with *k*.

The process will thus stop when *T<sub>k</sub>* is higher than *n*. We can thus determine that: *T<sub>k</sub> > n*, and thus *k×(k+1)/2 > T<sub>k</sub>* and thus *k<sup>2</sup>/2 + k/2 - n > 0*. This is a quadratic equation with as discriminant *d = 1/4 + 2×n*, and thus as (positive) solution *k<sub>0</sub>=-1/2 + √d*. It thus scales with *√2n*.

Answer (score 2):

To help you in your reasoning you could do experimental tests to count the number of iterations. For example:

```
for n in range(100000000, 1000000000, 100000000) :   
    i = 0
    s = 0
    while s <= n:
        s += i
        i += 1
```

and get the following results:

```
    n       | iterations|   sqrt(n)
-------------------------------------
100000000   |   14143   |   10000.00
200000000   |   20001   |   14142.14
300000000   |   24496   |   17320.51
400000000   |   28285   |   20000.00
500000000   |   31624   |   22360.68
600000000   |   34642   |   24494.90
700000000   |   37418   |   26457.51
800000000   |   40001   |   28284.27
900000000   |   42427   |   30000.00
```

---

#### EDIT

As recommended by @WillNess You can learn more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth)

Comment: cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth

Comment: Thanks, I added your link to the answer @WillNess

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the code `s = 1 + 2 + 3 + .... + i` (1) and `s <= n` (2). The first equation can also be written as `s = i * (i + 1) / 2` which means that in `i` is approximately `sqrt(s * 2)` and `sqrt(n * 2)`, and as we see from the code the `while` loop runs `i` time, each does a `O(1)` calculation. Therefore the overall complexity is `O(sqrt(n))`