# What time complexity is this nested loop with multiplication?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

educative.io think that the below code has complexity log<sub>2</sub>(n!) because `var` increases for each value of n.

However, my associate and I think that because `var` is always `< n` there is no way that it could be log2(n!) because it would never take more time than if the while loop just ran off `n`. The time complexity if `n` were used in the while predicate is n*log<sub>2</sub>(n).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 10;   

    for (int var = 0; var < n; var++) {   
      int j = 1;  
      while(j < var) { 
        j *= 2;  
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is log2(n!). Are you forgetting the log part and maybe thinking that it's being reported as n!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're both right. First, the case for why it's O(log n!):

- If you add up the cost of each individual iteration, the overall runtime is O(log 1 + log 2 + ... + log n).
- By the product rule of logarithms, log a + log b = log a×b.
- Therefore, O(log 1 + log 2 + ... + log n) = O(log 1×2×...×n) = O(log n!).

Once that's established, it can be shown that [O(log n!) = O(n log n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-%CE%98n-logn/2095472). They are actually the same complexity class.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider this statement and you both are right:

```
O(n*lg(n))=O(lg(n!))
```