# In an algorithm is O(log(N!)) faster than O(N)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Given two algorithms to solve a problem, one with time complexity O(log(N!)) and another with O(N), which of the two will be faster?

Comment: Please show your own attempt at solving this.

Comment: Your [guess](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+log2%28700%21%29+bigger+than+log2%28700%29+%3F) ? do [edit] to include the [details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)..

Comment: Aside from the duped question solving the interesting part of this question, you can't say which of two algorithms is faster given only big-O information. Big O gives eventual upper bounds (up to a constant multiple), which says nothing about actual performance without additional assumptions or information (for example, that the given big-O bounds are actually big-Theta bounds, as is often the case).

Answer (score 3):

O(log(n!)) Is the same as O(n*log(n)), so O(n) has the better worst-case.

See also [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-Θn-logn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-%CE%98n-logn)