# Determine runtime complexity of following algorithm

Tags: algorithm, runtime, complexity-theory

I have to determine the runtime complexity of the following algorithm (see picture).
I know how to do so theoretically, but for this specific example I'm having a hard time and also have no sample solution to see if I'm corrrect.

If someone could review my answer and correct it and maybe even give a explanation of the correct solution, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Overall --> Θ(n^2)
    for(int i=42; i<n*Math.log(n); i++)Θ(n)  
        foo(i);                        Θ(n*log2(n))
        for(int j=1; j<4711; j=j*3)    Θ(n)
            bar(i*j);                  Θ(log2(n))
```

```
foo(int n)                             --> Θ(n*log2(n))
    if(n%2 == 0)                       Θ(1)
        for(int i=1; i<2*n; i=i+2)     Θ(n)
            bar(i);                    Θ(log2(n))
    else                               --> Θ(n*log2(n))
        for(int i=1; i<n; i++)         Θ(n)
            bar(n);                    Θ(log2(n))
```

```
bar(int m)                              --> Θ(log2(n))
     while(m>0)                         Θ(log2(n))
         m = m/4;                       Θ(1)
```

Comment: @user1984 Sorry for the unfinished post, i needed a bit to embed the code and add my comments. It should be better now!

Comment: @Muhteva it is supposed to be bar(i) for the first loop and bar(n) for the second loop

Comment: That's great @DRock99 thank you for improving it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Time complexity of `bar(int m)` is `O(log(m))`. It's actually `log_4(m)`, however it can be converted to log base 2 like this: `log_4(m) = log_2(m) / log_2(4)`. And `log_2(4)` is constant. Therefore it's `O(log(m))`. Your analysis is correct.
2. Time complexity of `foo(int n)` is calculated like this: In first loop, we start from 1 and go to `2n` two by two. It takes `n` iterations. In second loop, we start from 1 and go to `n` one by one. It takes `n` iterations. Complexity of `bar(n)` is `O(log(n))`. However complexity of `bar(i)` depends on `i`, not `n`. It's `O(log(i))`. So total number of operations can be calculated like this: 
   If `n` is even, then number of total operations: 
   `log(1)` + `log(3)` + ... + `log(2n)` = `A` 
   Now, we know that `A` <= `nlog(2n)` = `O(nlogn)`. 
   We also know that `A >= log(1) + log(2)+ ... + log(n) = log(n!) = nlogn = O(nlogn)`. (*) 
   Therefore we squeezed `A` between `O(nlogn)` and `O(nlogn)`, therefore time complexity for `A` is `O(nlogn)`. 
   If `n` is odd, then it is: 
   `log(n)` + `log(n)` + ... + `log(n)` = `nlog(n)`
   Your time complexity analysis for the second part is completely correct.
3. We call `foo(i)` approximately `nlog(n)` times. Then we call `bar(i*j)` 8 times. Notice that as `n` increases, this value doesn't change. Therefore we can ignore `j` since it's not really a variable based on input size. Time complexity of `bar(i*j)` is proportional to `log(i)`. 
   So overall, if `i` is even. Number of operations: 
   `ilog(i)` + 8 * `log(i)`. 
   It's the same when `i` is odd. In total: 
   Sum of `ilog(i)` from `i=42` to `i=nlog(n)` 
   `42log(42) + 43log(43) + ... + nlog(n)log(nlog(n)) <= nlog(n)*nlog(n)*log(nlog(n)) = O(n^2 * log(n)^3))` 
   Time complexity of the whole function is `O(n^2 * log(n)^3)`.

(*) If you wonder how we switched from `log(n!)` to `nlog(n)`. Refer to [Is log(n!) = Θ(n·log(n))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-%CE%98n-logn)

Comment: Awesome, thank you, i do actually understand it now!

Comment: It doesn't call bar(i*j) 4711/3 times; it calls it 8 times  ( j *= 3, not j += 3). But that's a detail.