# Why log(n!) is O(nlog(n)) and not O(log(n!))

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, factorial

I understand the math here

```
n! < n^n.
```

But why can't the complexity simply be just `O(log(n!))`?

Why is there a need, given `f(n) ~ O(g(n))`, `f(n) != g(n)` is a must ? I repeatedly see the pattern in textbooks. Can't comprehend the need for it.

Is it because we want to map all f(n)'s to a limited list of g(n)'s - `logn, n, nlogn, n^2, n^3` etc?

Ex -
[Is log(n!) = Θ(n·log(n))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395)  Why can't it just be `O(log(n!))`

Comment: Nope, `f(n) != g(n)` is not a requirement. `log(n!)` *is* `O(log(n!))`.

Comment: What if you designed a sorting algorithm and had proof that it has O(log(!)) complexity, how will you compare it with existing sorting algorithms of which we know they have O(log) complexity?

Comment: comparison shouldn't be a problem.  log(n!) < nlogn  plain maths...

Comment: You have a type in second line. Repeat O(log(n!)) twice. Please fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with `n!`, [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) can be used:

```
n! ~ sqrt(2 * pi * n) * n^n / exp(n)
```

For `O(log n!)` we have:

```
O(log(n!)) = O(log(sqrt(2*pi*n) * n^n / exp(n))) =
           = O(log(sqrt(2*pi*n))) + O(log(n^n)) - O(log(exp(n))) =
           = O(1) + O(log(n)) + O(n * log(n)) - O(n) =
           = O(n * log(n))
```

Note, that `O(n * log(n))` is *simpler form* of `O(log(n!))` that's why we often prefer `O(n * log(n))` to original formula in textbooks.